# Calling pointer-to-member function in call for a function passed to a template function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, function-pointers, argument-passing

**This is the provided function template I'm trying to use:**

```
template <class Process, class BTNode>
void postorder(Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
{
   if (node_ptr != 0)
   {
      postorder( f, node_ptr->left() );
      postorder( f, node_ptr->right() );
      f( node_ptr->data() );
   }
}
```

**This is my call, and the function I'm passing:**

```
void city_db::print_bst() {
   postorder(&city_db::print, head);
}

void city_db::print(city_record target)
{
   std::cout << target.get_code();
}
```

**This is the compile time (G++) error I get:**

> CityDb.cpp:85:   instantiated from
>   here
>
> BinTree.template:80: error: must use
>   ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call
>   pointer-to-member function in ‘f
>   (...)’
>
> make: *** [CityDb.o] Error 1

This is in reference to the line `f( node_ptr->data() );` in the function template.

This is for a Data Structures project. The assignment was modified so we don't need to pass a function to a function, but I've been interested in this for quite some time, and I feel like I almost have it here. I've exhausted Google and Lab TA's, so if StackOverflow has ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that postorder accepts a function object that must be called this way:

```
f(arg);
```

You are passing in a pointer to member function. You should first call mem_fun to make a function object from the pointer to member:

```
std::mem_fun(&city_db::print)
```

The returned function object takes two arguments: the pointer to a city_db (the implicit this pointer), and the object to be printed. You can bind the first to this with bind1st, like this:

```
std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&city_db::print), this)
```

And now you should be able to call postorder on it:

```
postorder(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&city_db::print), this), head);
```

Comment: This took me a few minutes to understand this, but once it clicked it makes perfect sense. Thanks for breaking it down into manageable pieces. The final line solved the build errors.

Answer (score 3):

You need an instance of `city_db` to call `print` on.

What you're passing is a pointer to a member function (think of it as a slot in the vtable), but you need a `this` pointer too. You could pass this in as another argument to the `postorder` function.

```
template <class Object, class Process, class BTNode>
void postorder(Object* obj, Process f, BTNode* node_ptr)
{
   if (node_ptr != 0)
   {
      postorder(obj, f, node_ptr->left() );
      postorder(obj, f, node_ptr->right() );
      ((obj)->*(f))( node_ptr->data() );
   }
}
```

See [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5)

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.5 This section of the FAQ gives some helpful pointers to making the syntax a little cleaner.  In general I would prefer Thomas' answer.

Comment: Although I could probably modify it, I am treating BinTree as a large library to be left unmodified.

This is a good look at what's going on underneath though, and thanks for the resource, added to delicious to check next time I have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make city_db::print() static or provide a city _db object.

Answer (score 0):

As written

```
void city_db::print(city_record target)
{
   std::cout << target.get_code();
}
```

Does not depend on the class state. Declare it as a static function and compiler will not need `this` pointer to call it.
[FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) on the topic.

Comment: While this is true for this example, it sidesteps the whole issue of a pointer to a member function.